# How to handle git add * renamed:

Tags: git

I use git for a project. Structure like below

from:

```
*** Some files ***
/templates/
- header.php
- footer.php
*** Some files ***
```

to:

```
*** Some files ***
/templates/
- layout.php
*** Some files ***
```

I run this commands:

```
git add *
git status
```

result:

```
deleted:    footer.php
renamed:    header.php -> layout.php
```

I try to make:

```
deleted:    footer.php
deleted:    header.php
new file:   layout.php
```

All files in the same sub-folder

Answer (score 1):

Git sees that the content in the new file is content it expected in the old file, hence the "renamed" status. One way to get around this would be to do the deletions in one commit, and the creation of the new file in a separate commit after that one. This should make git treat them as distinct files.